# Error: Expected params.Item['id'].N to be a string

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

Here's the deal:

I am not able to add data to DynamoDB. JS file is in S3, here's the code:

```
var date = new Date(),
    item = {
        'id': {N: date.getTime()},
        'user': {S: "Sam"}
    },
    params = {
        TableName: 'users',
        Item: item
    };
dynamodb.putItem(params,function(err,data){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("user added to DynamoDB");
    }
});
```

Here's the screenshot from the DB which means that the `id` should be a number, not string:

[image]

The error I get:

> Error: Expected params.Item['id'].N to be a string
>
> ```
> at ParamValidator.fail (aws-sdk.js:96666)
> at ParamValidator.validateType (aws-sdk.js:96827)
> at ParamValidator.validateString (aws-sdk.js:96762)
> at ParamValidator.validateScalar (aws-sdk.js:96742)
> at ParamValidator.validateMember (aws-sdk.js:96709)
> at ParamValidator.validateStructure (aws-sdk.js:96690)
> at ParamValidator.validateMember (aws-sdk.js:96703)
> at ParamValidator.validateMap (aws-sdk.js:96729)
> at ParamValidator.validateMember (aws-sdk.js:96707)
> at ParamValidator.validateStructure (aws-sdk.js:96690)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you created the DynamoDB Table, the data type of the id
   (supposedly HashKey?) parameter you provided probably was String and
   not Number.
2. When you are trying to add an item to the table, you are probably
   providing it as Number (based on new Date().getTime()).
3. Please check the create table command that you originally issued.
4. To fix this issue, you may need to delete the table and create it
   again with the correct data type for the id attribute.

Comment: AWS ..no comment.

Answer (score 35):

I just had the issue myself.

Dynamo expect the "N" value to be a string, it's a bit misleading since you expect to pass a number to it.

where you have your date.getTime(), try to translate it into a string.

```
'id': { N: date.getTime().toString() },
```

That worked for me.

Comment: I just had this exactly same problem.  OMG Dynamo is poo sometimes.

Comment: That's the same issue I had. Even numbers should be passed as strings which is counter-intuitive.

Comment: Mental gymnastics indeed.  I was blazing until I got to DynamoDB but the alternative with Amplify is I start prefixing Mongo Atlas for each env I setup...

Answer (score 8):

Even when you want to **save** the value as a **number** in DynamoDB, you still need to **send** a **string** to the SDK, and so, you'll need to:

```
var date = new Date(),
    item = {
        'id': {N: date.getTime().toString()},
        'user': {S: "Sam"}
    },
    params = {
        TableName: 'users',
        Item: item
    };
dynamodb.putItem(params,function(err,data){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("user added to DynamoDB");
    }
});
```